# Rest service - cannot find method / operation

Tags: rest, cxf, jax-rs

Thought I had some idea of how the urls are mapped, but not having any luck here.
CXF 2.7.3

I have a simple rest service that uses post to consume a string.  It builds and deploys.

I think I should be attempting to hit the following url:

```
http://localhost:9764/workflow-management-service/services/createWorkflow?type=media-metadata
```

my cxf-servlet.xml

```
<jaxrs:server id="workflowManagementServer" address="/">
```

my web.xml

```
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

resource class

@Path("/")     class level

createWorkFlow method annotations
    @POST
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/createWorkflow")

Log when using url above from a browser.

> [2013-05-10 13:47:28,798] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  Trying to select a resource class, request pa
>   th : /createWorkflow
>   [2013-05-10 13:47:28,798] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  Trying to select a resource operation on the
>   resource class com.dg.cvp.workflow.WorkflowManagementResource
>   [2013-05-10 13:47:28,799] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  No method match, method name : createWorkflow
>   , request path : /createWorkflow, method @Path : /createWorkflow, HTTP Method : GET, method HTTP Method : POST, ContentT
>   ype : */*, method @Consumes : text/plain,, Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,, me
>   thod @Produces : application/xml,application/json,.
>   [2013-05-10 13:47:28,804] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  No method match, method name : createWorkflow
>   , request path : /createWorkflow, method @Path : /createWorkflow, HTTP Method : GET, method HTTP Method : POST, ContentT
>   ype : */*, method @Consumes : text/plain,, Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,, me
>   thod @Produces : application/xml,application/json,.
>   [2013-05-10 13:47:28,813] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  No method match, method name : createWorkflow
>   , request path : /createWorkflow, method @Path : /createWorkflow, HTTP Method : GET, method HTTP Method : POST, ContentT
>   ype : */*, method @Consumes : text/plain,, Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,, me
>   thod @Produces : application/xml,application/json,.
>   [2013-05-10 13:47:28,814] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  No method match, method name : createWorkflow
>   , request path : /createWorkflow, method @Path : /createWorkflow, HTTP Method : GET, method HTTP Method : POST, ContentT
>   ype : */*, method @Consumes : text/plain,, Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,, me
>   thod @Produces : application/xml,application/json,.
>   [2013-05-10 13:47:28,816] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  Trying to select a resource operation on the
>   resource class com.dg.cvp.workflow.WorkflowManagementResource
>   [2013-05-10 13:47:28,816] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  No method match, method name : createWorkflow
>   , request path : /createWorkflow, method @Path : /createWorkflow, HTTP Method : GET, method HTTP Method : POST, ContentT
>   ype : */*, method @Consumes : text/plain,, Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,, me
>   thod @Produces : application/xml,application/json,.
>   [2013-05-10 13:47:28,824] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  No method match, method name : createWorkflow
>   , request path : /createWorkflow, method @Path : /createWorkflow, HTTP Method : GET, method HTTP Method : POST, ContentT
>   ype : */*, method @Consumes : text/plain,, Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,, me
>   thod @Produces : application/xml,application/json,.
>   [2013-05-10 13:47:28,834] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  No method match, method name : createWorkflow
>   , request path : /createWorkflow, method @Path : /createWorkflow, HTTP Method : GET, method HTTP Method : POST, ContentT
>   ype : */*, method @Consumes : text/plain,, Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,, me
>   thod @Produces : application/xml,application/json,.
>   [2013-05-10 13:47:28,835] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  No method match, method name : createWorkflow
>   , request path : /createWorkflow, method @Path : /createWorkflow, HTTP Method : GET, method HTTP Method : POST, ContentT
>   ype : */*, method @Consumes : text/plain,, Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,, me
>   thod @Produces : application/xml,application/json,.
>   [2013-05-10 13:47:28,843]  WARN {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  No operation matching request path "/workflow
>   -management-service/services/createWorkflow" is found, Relative Path: /createWorkflow, HTTP Method: GET, ContentType: */
>   *, Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more
>    details.
>   [2013-05-10 13:47:28,853] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper} -  WebApplicationException has
>    been caught, status: 405
>   javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
>           at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:413)

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else new to rest, using a browser address bar to post doesn't make sense.

Found a great chrome extension (Advanced REST Client) to test all manner of rest services,
soapui is another widely used client